# Grid 1x3 donde los primeros dos elementos van a la izquierda y el tercero a la derecha

Tags: css, css-grid-layout

Tengo un simple grid donde me gustaría los dos primeros elementos se ajusten y peguen a la izquierda, mientras que el último se vaya al final.
Por algún motivo el `justify-self` no funciona.

También podría trabajar con proporciones utilizando templates pero `primero` y `segundo` no son de tamaño fijo.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 2rem;
  width: 100%
  
}

.primero{ background: tomato}
.segundo{ background: gold}
.tercero{ 
  background: cyan; 
  justify-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="primero">primero</div>
  <div class="segundo">segundo</div>
  <div class="tercero">tercero a la derecha</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este caso en especifico te recomiendo usar `flex` en lugar de `grid` y darle un `margin-left: auto` al ultimo elemento asi siempre se alineara al final

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
  width: 100%
}

.primero {
  background: tomato
}

.segundo {
  background: gold
}

.tercero {
  background: cyan;
  justify-self: flex-end;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="primero">primero</div>
  <div class="segundo">segundo</div>
  <div class="tercero">tercero a la derecha</div>
</div>
```